# libusb installed- but pyUSB backend not found

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb

I am trying to design a GUI using wxGlade for a USB device. The pyUSB portion of the code has been added to the python code generated by Glade.

However, there is an error. 'No backend available'

This is is response to using a function usbDev = usb.core.find(idVendor = 0xfffe, idProduct = 0x0001)

I have already installed libusb-win32 and still it doesn't work. I restarted the PC once, but to no avail. Kindly help.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem too.

Then, I tried ActivePython2.7.x.x

Link->http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

Download the 2.7.x.x 32-bit version. The 64-bit version doesn't allow the installation of pyusb!

Then install pyusb and proceed.

Works fine.